# Public key not found ("No such file or directory") when appending it to the authorized_keys2 file of the target machine I want to send files to

Tags: docker, networking, ssh

Following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-copy-a-docker-image-from-one-server-to-another-without-pushing-it-to-a-repository-first), I want to transfer a Docker image from my Windows10 PC to another one, Fedora, using rsync. So I need verified SSH access between the two machines. So I follow [this tutorial](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/hee/cms/emu/fast/FAST-DAQ/ssh_between_2.html) but I have problems authorizing the public key. I am not able to do this by logging into the machine and then appending the public key to the authorized_keys2 file.

I manage to connect to Fedora with SSH. Side note: I don't know if it is enough to transfer a Docker image.

So if I follow the tutorial to connect without login correctly I also have to authorize the public key (on the target machine?) (Step 3.)

But while I am able to connect with SSH to the target machine, I am not able to transfer the public key.

```
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> ssh-keygen -t dsa -f 192.168.1.123
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in 192.168.1.123.
Your public key has been saved in 192.168.1.123.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:necesitoOcultarLosi? antoi@DESKTOP-QL4RO3V
The key's randomart image is:
+---[DSA 1024]----+
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
+----[SHA256]-----+
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> scp 192.168.1.123.pub me@192.168.1.123
        1 file(s) copied.
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> ssh me@192.168.1.123
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.123 port 22: Connection timed out
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> ssh me@192.168.1.123
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.123 port 22: Connection refused
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> ssh me@192.168.1.123
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.123 port 22: Connection refused
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> ssh me@192.168.1.123
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.123 port 22: Connection refused
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> ssh me@192.168.1.123
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.123 port 22: Connection refused
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> ssh me@192.168.1.123
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.123 (192.168.1.123)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:S5iZ1NAjwVKK/75sy6TerzplQdCT6bDYI1Fx72h+V1g.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.123' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
me@192.168.1.123's password:
Last login: Wed Dec 22 14:26:46 2021
cat: 192.168.1.123.pub: No such file or directory
[me@fedora ~]$

[me@fedora ~]$ cat 192.168.1.123.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
cat: 192.168.1.123.pub: No such file or directory
```

What can I do? In the worst case I can send you an email. But I don't know if this will solve my initial image transfer problem.

Comment: The usual approach is to use a Docker image registry, something like Docker Hub, or one hosted by your cloud provider, or one you run yourself, and then you can `docker push` from one machine and `docker pull` on another.  Neither setting up a registry nor the ssh configuration you're asking about is really the sort of programming-related question that's on topic for Stack Overflow, though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DavidMaze however my company doesn’t have or use a cloud. And I there are nodes I don’t want to show up online. That’s why I decided to ssh between these two machines. Is there a better alternative ?

Comment: I'd recommend [running your own registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) in that case.  Whatever solution you already have for publishing the results of builds might also work.